Arduino CLI is unable to get Documents folder
I'm attempting to use Arduino CLI on a Windows Build Server (Windows Server 2022 Datacenter Azure Edition) to compile some Arduino code. My Arduino code is hosted in Github, and I have a YAML file/Github Action configured such that a build is kicked off on this Windows server whenever I merge into my target branch.
Whenever I get to a step in my Github Actions that involves the Arduino CLI, I see: Unable to get Documents Folder: The system cannot find the file specified.

This screenshot shows the step where I install the ESP32 Core libraries, but all other steps involving arduino-cli produce this same message.
I understand that the arduino-cli is attempting to find my Documents folder. When I connect to my build server manually and execute an arduino-cli command as my local admin, I do not see this message. Apparently, my Github Action is running as nt authority/system, so it makes sense that arduino-cli is not able to find a Documents folder while running as this user. My question is: Is there a way to manually specify a "Documents" folder for the Arduino-CLI? If not, is there a way to execute as a different user?
I'm running 64bit Arduino CLI, Version 1.0.1.

I found some answers to my above two questions.
First, in regards to whether or not we can specify a folder to use as "Documents", it turns out that the Arduino CLI is open source. Looking at this block of code specifically, it seems that the Arduino CLI uses win32.GetDocumentsFolder() to get the folder. I noticed another file that appears to uses an environment variable, but I wasn't able to get this to work. Besides this, I wasn't sure if the "Documents" issue is the only side effect of using the System user. As such, I decided to execute my scripts as a different user.
To execute as another user, I used New-PSSession and Invoke-Command to run my Arduino CLI scripts within my YAML file. For example:
  - name: Run Arduino CLI Installation scripts
    shell: powershell
    run: |
        $password = "${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
        $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "MyDomain\MyUser",$password
        $MySession = New-PSSession -Credential $cred
        Invoke-Command -Session $MySession -ScriptBlock { 
            whoami 
            arduino-cli core update-index --config-file arduino-cli.yaml
            arduino-cli lib install ArduinoJson@7.1.0 
            arduino-cli core install esp32:esp32@2.0.5
            cd C:\actions-runner\_work\MyDir
            arduino-cli compile -b esp32:esp32:esp32s2 --output-dir .\bin
        }
        

Note that I stored the password in Github to avoid exposing it in the script itself (i.e. My Github Repo > Settings > "Secrets and Variables" > Actions > Secrets)

Does this method still work if the user has a PIN?

@slinky55 - I don't think it does, but it would be interesting to try. Here's some documentation on the PS Credential: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscredential?view=powershellsdk-7.4.0#definition
